# VLSM Calculation

Tags: networking, cisco

```
Network - 193.197.74.0 /24
```

There are 6 routers : A,B,C,D,E,F

```
router A - DMZ - 12 
router B - 60hosts
router C  - 20hosts
router D - 10 hosts
router E - 25hosts
router F - 50hosts
```

These routers are connected in a ring topology

There a conditions given below before I can calcuate the VLSM.

1. Subnet zero and last subnet(1-bit subnets) are forbidden 
   "By this I understand that it means, the first possible subnet address and the last possible subnet address should not be used. "

2.The lowest and highest subnet IPs are for normal serial inter router connection 
" By this I understand, that the network address should be given for connections between Router A - Router B - and so no." *Is that correct?*

3 - The biggest subnet should be in the middle of possible address
"In cisco netacad, I read that the highest possible address should be taken first , with that I can calculate the subnet mask and the first and last possible hosts"

4 - The lower in size matching subnet is to use a DMZ - Network
" Does that mean that , I have to choose the lowest subnet -  (Least possible hosts) and pick that for DMZ"

I need no solution for this, but I just to understand the question correctly that way I can solve it.

My understanding were mentioned above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Nowadays by default in cisco routers no subnet zero is enabled that means you can use first subnet for allocation.
2)cisco has behaviour of longest possible match means if you have two networks to reach same destination 10.1.1.0/27 and 10.1.1.0/30 then second one will go in routing table as cisco starts counting network address from LSB which in this case is 32 then 31 then /30 ITS HIT AND GOES TO ROUTE TABLE.

Plan acordingly and note that LONGEST POSSIBLE MATCH has an precedence over AD value of routing protocols value.